# how to remove empty value after we do preprocessing text in python

Tags: python, text-mining, preprocessor

e.g
I have a tweet "@cintya @groot @smanela https://blog..."
and I do a preprocessing process that link and mention has been deleted, and I think it should be lost. 
But in CSV, they return an empty value. How can I fix them?
Here is my code

```
def replaceMultiple(mainString, toBeReplaces, newString):
    for elem in toBeReplaces :
        if elem in mainString :
            mainString = mainString.replace(elem, newString)
    return  mainString

with open('datalatihNegatif.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        _word = []
        username = row[0]
        date = row[1]
        text = row[2].lower()
        text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0-9_]+','',text)
        text = re.sub(r'http\S+', '',text)

        text = replaceMultiple(text, ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",
                                      ")","_","-","+","=","{","}","[","]",
                                      "\\","/",",",".","?","<",">",":",";",
                                      "'",'"',"~","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"], '')
        text = text.strip()
        nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
        stop_words = set(stopwords.words("indonesian"))
        stop_words_new = ['i','liked','video','an','at','ba','da','do','ka','ma','ta','uh','yg','al','eh','ha','ah','ng']
        new_stopwords_list = stop_words.union(stop_words_new)

        print(username)
        print(date)

        for word in nltk_tokens:
            if word not in new_stopwords_list:
                if stemmer.stem(word) != "":
                    _word.append(stemmer.stem(word))
        print(_word)
        csvFile = open('preprocessingDLNegatif.csv', 'a', newline='')
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
        csvWriter.writerow(_word)
        csvFile.close()
```

I expect the result in CSV is deleted, but the actual output is empty value 1 row in CSV
[481 is empty value, how can i remove it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgTOF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking for anything in `_word` before you write it out:

```
if len(_word) != 0:
    csvFile = open('preprocessingDLNegatif.csv', 'a', newline='')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter.writerow(_word)
    csvFile.close()
```

I also wouldn't open an close the output file for every record you write. Open it once before looping and close it when done. Doing so would make my answer look like:

```
if len(_word) != 0:
    csvWriter.writerow(_word)
```

Comment: Please accept as answer if this resolved your issue. Thanks!